# GCP and firebase gives me project limit error while I don't have any projects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have issue creating projects in my firebase and gcp account. Whenever I go to my console, it asks me to choose a project in order to use the service (To view this page, select a project.). But when I click on create a project I see the quota limitation error. What is the problem here is that when I click to select a project, I see "No Organisation". I really cannot use my account right now and I don't exactly know what could be the issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you have a look at it once.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Cloud Billing account to use Google Cloud. To use Google Cloud resources in a project, billing must be enabled on the project. Billing is enabled when the project is linked to an active Cloud Billing account.

**Important:** Projects that are not linked to an active Cloud Billing account cannot use Google Cloud

If you are an existing Google Cloud user, the organization resource will be created for you when you create a new project or billing account. Any projects you created previously will be listed under "No organization", and this is normal. The organization resource will appear and the new project you created will be linked to it automatically.

Check this document on [Create a new Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/create-billing-account) & [Creating and managing organization resources](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization)

There could be a few other possibilities causing the issue

- Reached  max project limit for her organization
- Reached your project quota for your account.

Each account has a limit on the amount of resources that can be used by all of its projects. To check your account's project quota, go to the Billing page in the Cloud Console and click on Project quotas.If you've reached the limit, you'll need to delete or archive some existing projects before creating new ones.

The account may be suspended. If an account is suspended, you will not be able to create new projects. To check if your account is suspended, go to the Billing page in the Cloud Console and click on Account status.

If you are still facing the issue, I recommend reaching out to [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for further assistance as your account will be inspected by the team.

Comment: I've added a billing account, but still I get the same error that I cannot increase my resources. I cannot see any projects

Comment: The account may be suspended. If an account is suspended, you will not be able to create new projects. To check if your account is suspended, go to the Billing page in the Cloud Console and click on Account status.

Comment: I don't see any account status in the billing page. I go to the billing page, select the billing account that I just created and then go to the account management page and I don't see anything regarding the account suspension